# How to traverse from this tree and get their attributes?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, parent-child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent>

<child ID="1" Name="CHILD" Order="1">

<child ID="1" Name="SUB_CHILD" Order="1">
<child ID="1" Name="SUB_CHILD_1" Order="01"/>
<child ID="2" Name="SUB_CHILD_2" Order="02"/>
</child >

</child>

<child ID="2" Name="CHILD_2" Order="1">

<child ID="1" Name="SUB_CHILD" Order="1">
<child ID="1" Name="SUB_CHILD_1" Order="01"/>
<child ID="2" Name="SUB_CHILD_2" Order="02"/>
</child >

</child>

</parent>
```

This is my code in getting the `<child ID="1" Name="CHILD" Order="1">` Name:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("child");

        Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(0);
        name = element.getAttribute("Name");            

        Toast.makeText(this, ""+ name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

How do I get the Name of:

```
<child ID="1" Name="SUB_CHILD" Order="1">
<child ID="1" Name="SUB_CHILD_1" Order="01"/>
```

I have already tried getChildNode but it only returns nothing.

Comment: getElementsByTagName("CATEGORY").. you have no elements named Category so this will fail.

Comment: @dymmeh Sorry. Edited my code. I'm very sleepy. I have been working on this code for so long. I can't get it to work.